# What is n_components in NMF(Non-Negative Matrix Factorization) in sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine, nmf

What is `n_components` in `sklearn.NMF`?

```
nmf = NMF(n_components=2, init='random', random_state=0)
nmf.fit(V)
```

Comment: Read [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization) and replace *features* with *components*,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one example of how I've seen this parameter used:

When used for topic modeling in natural language processing, `n_components` can be used as the number of topics to print out.

For example, if I fit the NMF object on a TF-IDF vectorizer and set `n_components` = 10, I can use it to show me 10 different collections of words that I can interpret as my topics.